# Rails 2, authenticity tokens, and monitors

Tags: monitoring, login, network-monitoring, ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to monitor a rails app that is behind a login page? We are currently using Zabbix for all of our monitoring needs, but based on [this](http://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=10661) forum post it doesn't seem like it is currently possible due to the authenticity token that prevents cross site scripting.

Is there any way to check the status of our app? Ideally, it just needs to be able to login and verify a valid HTTP response code. I am open to any additional monitor solutions you can recommend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can use JSON and get around the authenticity token.